# Find the Lie bracket between the vector fields $\partial_x$ and $x\partial_z+\partial_y$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

We consider $v = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $w = x * \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

I need to first find the Lie bracket between them which i get to be: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} * x * \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - x * \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial x}.$

Now assuming $f$ is smooth, and $L_{v}f = L_{w}f = 0,$ i need to show that $f$ is constant.

I am trying to show that $L_{u}f = 0$ for all vectors $u$ first, and then use $f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0)) =  \int_0^1 L_{\gamma(t)}f\,dt.$

But i am at a loss because, i need the gradient of $f$ to compute $L_{u}f$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Lie bracket of two vector fields should be a vector field - the second derivatives should cancel out.

Comment: Regarding the second question, my hint is that $vf,wf$ being zero implies $[v,w]f=0$ as well.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Sorry Anthony, maybe you could elaborate a bit more? I am just getting my feet wet with Lie Algebras...

Comment: the correct way to flag a question as answered is to accept an answer, not to edit the title.

Answer (score 2):

You messed something up in the first computation - the Lie bracket of two vector fields is always a vector field. In this case we have 
$$[\partial_x, x\partial_z + \partial_y] = [\partial_x, \partial_y] + \partial_x\circ(x\partial_z) - x\partial_z \circ \partial_x = (\partial_x x)\partial_z = \partial_z.$$

For the second question, remember that the Lie derivative of a function is just the usual directional derivative - so if we can show $L_u f = 0$ for all $u$ in a basis/frame then $f$ must be (locally) constant. We are given $L_v f = L_w f = 0$, which implies that $L_{[v,w]} f = (L_v L_w -L_w L_v)f=L_v(0)-L_w(0)=0$. We now have the facts

$$ \partial_x f = x \partial_z f + \partial_y f = \partial_z f = 0.$$

Substituting $\partial_z f = 0$ into the middle expression gives $\partial_y f = 0$; so we have $\partial_x f = \partial_y f = \partial_z f = 0$.

Comment: ah, the bracket being that clears a lot up. My computation was bugging me. Thanks. Also, the way i think about Lie brackets is EXACTLY as commutators, so the way i would compute [X,Y] is exactly XY - YX. Is this the correct intuition about them?

Comment: @mindGame: correct - the bracket is exactly the commutator of derivatives $X \circ Y - Y \circ X$.